# Webscraping - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want the function to collect all the titles from the `img tags` and all the text from the `h3 tags`. The output of the loop is:

> "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"`.

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong?

```py
url = "https://www.historico.portugal.gov.pt/pt/o-governo/arquivo-historico/governos-constitucionais/gc18/composicao.aspx"

uClient = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

containers = soup.findAll("li")

container = containers[7]

for container in containers:
    name = container.img["alt"]
    j = container.findAll("h3", {"class":"mainForecolor"})
    job = c[0].text

    print("nome: " + name)
    print("cargo: " + job)
```

Comment: Post Complete traceback where said wich line is the error. You will have to protect the code with some IF when website doesnt contains your desired web element

Comment: The full message is "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". According to the html of the website, that shouldn't be a problem at least for the img tags, since all of them have what I want - and I've tried that. Could it be something wrong with the "names" var inside the loop?

Comment: so your error is on line 2? (uClient = urlopen(url))???

Comment: line 2 of the loop I believe, so in "name = container.img["alt"]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve names as below.

your container is of type `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` So you will need to iterate through it and then look for another tag `img` which is again of type `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` So, to retrieve any attribute/property of that tag you will need to iterate through it.

```py
url = "https://www.historico.portugal.gov.pt/pt/o-governo/arquivo-historico/governos-constitucionais/gc18/composicao.aspx"

uClient = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

container = soup.find_all('li')

for c in container:
    for link in c.findAll('img'):
        print("name : " +link.get('alt'))
```

Or if you want to skip the Li tag at all you can directly find all the img tags and work as below.

```py
container = soup.find_all('img')

for c in container:
    print("name : "+c.get('alt'))
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, both for your explanation and the code. It finally worked, and I finally understood

Comment: @JoãoJerónimo Glad that I could help! :)

Comment: @JoãoJerónimo also consider replacing `BeautifulSoup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")` with `BeautifulSoup(uClient.read(), "lxml")` as the lxml parser tends to be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

`container.img` does not exist, and thus is of the type `None` which cannot be subscripted in the manner `container.img['alt']`.

Why does `container.img` not exist? Well, `container` is going to be a BeautifulSoup `Tag` object which does not have an `img` property. Maybe you meant to access the attributes of the tag via `container['img']`. Unfortunately, for the example you've provided, none of the `container` Tags in `containers` has any attributes.

See:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag

Comment: How can I then loop over the title attribute over all of the img tags?

Comment: You could change: `containers = soup.findAll("li")` to `images = soup.find_all("img")` and then for each image in images: `img['alt']`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for the link!